# How to TypeScript the following jquery code?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have the following function:

```
$.getJSON("Hierarchy/Data").done((item) => {
   var data = item.Value;
});
```

I'm using https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped as Type definitions.

I'm trying to define a type for `item`, but I'm not able to find the appropriate type. I've tried to type it as `JQueryPromiseCallBack<MyInterface>`, but the compiler is saying, that the property Value doesn't exist.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JQueryPromiseCallBack` is typed to `any` in the `jquery.d.ts`-file. there is no way to change this, and there also should be no way.
The `JQueryPromiseCallBack` is always used by the `done`-function, independent from what you use it for.

The easiest way to meet your requirements would be a cast:

```
$.getJSON("Hierarchy/Data").done((item) => {
   var data = (<MyInterface>item).Value;
});
```